# gRPC Spring Boot Starter Maven Not Found

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, grpc-java

I created a simple maven spring boot `1.5.2.RELEASE` application with the help of Spring initilizr website to test `gRPC` with spring boot app. As anyone would do, i loop up for spring boot starter for `gRPC` to help for configuration complexity.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lognet</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is Maven does not seem to get this dependency. Error is `Dependency '''org.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0''' not found`

Is there any simple way to use gRPC with spring boot?

Comment: Same here, not able to find the dependency

Comment: @Yunus There is another project with the same name on https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter. Which one should we use? I am a bit confused..

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the jcenter repo like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
    }
}
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter {
       url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
   }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:2.1.4' // change with latest
```